# Is it possible to set Request.UrlReferrer in the client side javascript? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

I have this application that relies extensively on `Request.UrlReferrer` for handling link clicks and maintaining a page history of where a user has been in the application.

The requirements have changed and I now need to navigate in a certain location using `<input type="button" />` instead of `<a href="mypage.aspx"/>`

Currently I'm experimenting with

```
<input type="button" 
onclick='ShowLoadingScreen();document.write("<a id=\"link\" style=\"display:none;\" href=\"mypage.aspx\">link</a>");document.getElementById("link").click();'>
Do Thing
</input>
```

but the code is not as clean as I would like and writing to the document blows away my loading screen. If I set innerHTML of something on the page my click ceases to work.

From the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.urlreferrer.aspx#Y300)

> Clients can falsify or choose not to present a Referer header.
>   Therefore, while the UrlReferrer property can be useful for
>   identifying basic trends in Web traffic; you should not use it as part
>   of an authorization scheme to control access to data.

So it is possible to falsify it which would work wonderfully for my purposes. However I do not know how to achieve this.

Is there a way to fake the UrlReferrer using javascript so that I may keep my code to a minimum?
Something like

```
<input type="button" 
onclick='ShowLoadingScreen(); SetUrlReferrer(); window.location="mypage.aspx";'>
Do Thing
</input>
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

```
document.referrer = 'myref.aspx';
```

`Error: Object doesn't support this action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but i don't think that it will work. This is only possible if you build the http request by hand (even with ajax you will get problems on most browsers)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll keep on trying to get the alternative javascript hack to work.